# Brauer-Manin obstruction to surfaces of Kodaira dimension 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points

Roughly speaking, the Kodaira dimension is an invariant of a variety that corresponds to curvature. One can show that curves of genus $\geq 2$ have Kodaira dimension 1 using Riemann-Roch. In Corollary 4 of following [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0395v1.pdf), Bhargava shows that as the genus $g$ of the curve tends to infinity, a density approaching $100 \%$ of hyper-elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ of genus $g$ have a Brauer-Manin obstruction to having a rational point.

What do we know about Brauer-Manin obstructions to surfaces of Kodaira dimension 1? Or to elliptic surfaces? Any references and/or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One quick comment is that not every elliptic surface has Kodaira dimension one; a DP1 is an elliptic surface, and a lot is known (e.g. by Tony Varilly's thesis, there can be a BM obstruction to weak approximation on a DP1).